# Should the act tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, burninate-request

I think the [act](/questions/tagged/act) tag should be burninated, because

1. Only 4 questions with the **act** tag were asked this year.
2. I don't understand it, because it has no wiki summary.
3. Most of the questions asked with the [act](/questions/tagged/act) tag didn't even relate to an "ACT."
4. There are only 16 questions asked with the [act](/questions/tagged/act) total.

**Edit**

Please leave a comment on *why* you downvoted after you downvote.  Also, I now know that *act* is a customer and management relationship manager, but it seems as though not lots of people use it, as it only has 16 questions total, only 3 asked this year, so I think it should *still* be burninated.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  I clearly asked 'Should'.  After you downvote, please leave a comment saying *why.*

Comment: On meta voting is different and for something like this is a sign of agreement / disagreement with the proposed request to remove the tag. As per the answer it appears to be a valid tag, and even if not hugely popular a negative score just means most people (to date) think it should remain.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks, I better be more careful with my posts next time

Comment: I'm going to need a major post to make up for this lost rep :P

Comment: How are there 16 when I click the tag and only see 14 questions tagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Act! is the #1 best-selling Contact & Customer Manager, trusted by individuals, small businesses, and sales teams to get organized and take the guesswork out of marketing to drive sales results.

From [act.com](http://act.com/)

There appear to be legitimate programming questions about the product; it's just not used very often. I guess it just needs a good wiki.